# Harry potter legacy release for windows and raspberry pi desktop last model,how to make it work

Tags: windows, games

[image: minimum spec on pc for it]She is a beginner but has joined a monthly coding dojo that we will also consult

Comment: [Question, how do I ask](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `She is a beginner` ... we have no way of knowing who you are talking about

Answer (score 1):

Not possible to run Harry Potter Legacy on a Raspberry Pi.

You need a well specified Windows PC.

PC specifications here:

https://www.hogwartslegacy.com/en-gb/pc-specs